# indexOf of AnyObject array not working with Strings

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, indexof

So I'm having the following code in a playgroung

```
var array: [AnyObject] = ["", "2", "3"]

let index = array.indexOf("")
```

And XCode is marking a compiler error

`Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '@noescape (AnyObject) throws -> Bool'`

So my question is how do I get the indexOf an element in an Array in of AnyObjects?

Comment: Why don't you use `[String]`, you should rarely use `AnyObject` and especially in swift ! you should always specify whats your array is holding !

Comment: `AnyObject` is a placeholder for "unspecified". The array is obviously an array of strings, so just remove the annotation `[AnyObject]`. The compiler will infer the right thing.

Comment: What if the array is a NSArray defined in a objective C class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also cast to [String] if you're sure it will cast safely

```
jvar array: [AnyObject] = ["", "2", "3"]
let index = (array as! [String]).indexOf("")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var array = ["", "2", "3"]
let index = array.indexOf("")
```

or you can use the `NSArray` method:

```
var array: [AnyObject] = ["", "2", "3"]
let index = (array as NSArray).indexOfObject("")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `AnyObject` for a placeholder for any type, use `Any` instead. Reason: `AnyObject` only works with classes, Swift uses a lot of structs though (Array, Int, String, etc.). Your code actually uses `NSString`s instead of Swifts native `String` type because `AnyObject` wants a class (`NSString` is a class).

Comment: I agree with you I just used an easy way to illustrate my issue when having an `NSArray` defined in some objective c class and being accessed in a swift class.

Answer (score 0):

In more general cases, `collectionType.indexOf` will work when the object inside an array conforms to `Equatable` protocol. Since Swift `String` has already conformed to `Equatable`, then casts `AnyObject` to `String` will remove the error.

**How to use `indexOf` on collection type custom class ? Swift 2.3**

```
class Student{
   let studentId: Int
   let name: String
   init(studentId: Int, name: String){
     self.studentId = studentId
     self.name = name
   }
}

//notice you should implement this on a global scope
extension Student: Equatable{
}

func ==(lhs: Student, rhs: Student) -> Bool {
    return lhs.studentId == rhs.studentId //the indexOf will compare the elements based on this
}


func !=(lhs: Student, rhs: Student) -> Bool {
    return !(lhs == rhs)
}
```

Now you can use it like this

```
let john = Student(1, "John")
let kate = Student(2, "Kate")
let students: [Student] = [john, kate] 
print(students.indexOf(John)) //0
print(students.indexOf(Kate)) //1
```